# How can absolute positioning of a ul cause an overlap on buttons in a table?

Tags: html, css, html-table

Not sure if this is actually related to the table, but I have a popup that overlaps button elements in the next table row.

[image: Overlapping Issue]

I have tried:
1) making my z-index on the popup ul 20000
2) making the overlapping button have a relative position with a z-index
3) setting a specific relative position and z-index on each of the table rows
4) removing all positioning except for the popup
5) making the li's have a z-index greater than the button...
6) and a combination of the above
Could there be a bug with table having  `border-collapse: separate;`?
7) removed table border-collapse: separate;
8) removed table-layout: fixed;
9) checked to see if any z-index or positioning is used on the table

Cannot figure this little problem out. I do not have any z-index or position set on my buttons. They are `display: inline-block;` with some margin.
I cannot reproduce this in other places on the site.

CSS:

```
/* POPUPS */
.list-popup {/* this class is on the button */
    position: relative;
    z-index: 20;
}
.list-popup ul {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    top: 30px;
    right: 0;
    display: none;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1000;
}
.list-popup ul li{
    width: 200px;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

**EDIT:**
[Here is a fiddle of it *working*](https://jsfiddle.net/d82r7mnf/9/)
- Change the z-index in the popup class from 0 to 10 and you can see the difference. As mentioned above, I cannot reproduce this on other places in the application. I have checked references to other classes that could be effecting the z-index and can find none.

Comment: Have you tried putting all the `.list-popup ul li` at the same z-index?

Comment: Yes. It did not make a difference.

Comment: Just to confirm, the Note tooltip is related to the element that's above it right (the one that has a small blue shape showing?

Comment: It actually displays when the user clicks on the button with the ellipsis.

Comment: Could you upload it somewhere to see the full structure, it's kinda difficult to reproduce it like this.

Comment: It makes it difficult to help, but I cannot upload the code. I apologize. I recreated a fiddle with it. See above

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
/* POPUPS */
.list-popup {/* this class is on the button */
position: relative;
z-index: -2;
```

}

Comment: That makes the popup ul go behind all of the buttons. Which makes sense considering there is no position set and all the buttons are relative to a parent div.
Setting the same ul to 2000 goes above the buttons on it's own row, but still behind the button element in the row below

Comment: can u provide litlle more code for test the senario plz. I want to  check it.

Comment: Here is a fiddle... and I DID fix it by setting the z-index. in the popup class. But I cannot get that function the same on my application.
https://jsfiddle.net/d82r7mnf/7/